# Strings Compare with recursion in mips

Tags: assembly, recursion, mips

I am currently trying to implement a way of comparing 2 strings in mips assembly with recursion. I basically want to execute this instruction :
 int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2) with a recursive way. Is there anyone who could help me with how I should think, or an example? 
I searched for this in the site but I couldnt find anything assembly-related.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should show us what you've tried or thought so far.

Comment: well I have thought some steps, I start by loading the first letter of each string, then compare them. If they are not the same, I exit the program with an appropriate message. If they are the same, I check if there is a next letter in both my strings. If it exists, I load the next letter and compare etc etc. My problem is that I cant really grasp the recursive project. Should I take every next letter as first every time and "shorten" my strings that way? For example "example" and "exampd" should be "xample" and "xampd" after the first check?

Comment: Also, I thought I should first count the number of letters in each string, if they are different I should exit immediately.

Comment: To count you would need to traverse the whole string anyways, so that's not a very smart option. Your first algorithm is OK, you just need to think about it in a recursive manner instead of an iterative one. Try to write a pseudo-code with your idea and include it in the question, it will help getting help :)

Comment: okay I will try to do it first in c, thank you for your help!

Comment: jo941: A recursive iteration would be more complex, memory hungry and slow compared to a traditional loop. If you've decided that assembly language is the best approach to solve your problem then I'd suggest not to further complicating things any more than necessary until you have a firmer grasp of the language, and practice recursion on problems for which they are the the most straightforward solution.